# How to divide 1 completablefuture to many completablefuture in stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, completable-future

For example I have such methods:

```
public CompletableFuture<Page> getPage(int i) {
    ...
}
public CompletableFuture<Document> getDocument(int i) {
    ...
}
public CompletableFuture<Void> parseLinks(Document doc) {
    ...
}
```

And my flow:

```
List<CompletableFuture> list = IntStream
    .range(0, 10)
    .mapToObj(i -> getPage(i))

    // I want method like this:
    .thenApplyAndSplit(CompletableFuture<Page> page -> {
        List<CompletableFuture<Document>> docs = page.getDocsId()
            .stream()
            .map(i -> getDocument(i))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return docs;
    })
    .map(CompletableFuture<Document> future -> {
        return future.thenApply(Document doc -> parseLink(doc);
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It should by something like `flatMap()` for `CompletableFuture`, so I want to implement this flow:

```
List<Integer> -> Stream<CompletableFuture<Page>>
              -> Stream<CompletableFuture<Document>>
              -> parse each
```

**UPDATE**

```
Stream<CompletableFuture<Page>> pagesCFS = IntStream
        .range(0, 10)
        .mapToObj(i -> getPage(i));

Stream<CompletableFuture<Document>> documentCFS = listCFS.flatMap(page -> {
    // How to return stream of Document when page finishes?
    // page.thenApply( ... )
})
```

Comment: Basically you need to flatMap CompletableFuture into Stream<CompletableFuture>

Answer (score 2):

I also wanted to give a shot at implementing a `Spliterator` for `Stream<CompletableFuture>`, so here is my attempt.

This solution creates a `Stream` of the results of the futures, as soon as any of these futures complete. Of course this loses any ordering present in the original stream.

The original stream will be consumed immediately by the method, hence triggering the whole pipeline for all elements – thus losing the laziness of the original stream pipeline. It is assumed that building the stream is fast, the hard work being done by the futures themselves, so consuming the stream shouldn't be costly. This also makes sure that all tasks are already triggered, as it forces to process the source stream.

So here is the implementation:

```
public static <T> Stream<T> flattenStreamOfFutures(Stream<CompletableFuture<? extends T>> stream, boolean parallel) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(new CompletableFutureSpliterator<T>(stream), parallel);
}

public static <T> Stream<T> flattenStreamOfFuturesOfStream(Stream<CompletableFuture<? extends Stream<T>>> stream,
                                                           boolean parallel) {
    return flattenStreamOfFutures(stream, parallel).flatMap(Function.identity());
}

public static class CompletableFutureSpliterator<T> implements Spliterator<T> {
    private List<CompletableFuture<? extends T>> futures;

    CompletableFutureSpliterator(Stream<CompletableFuture<? extends T>> stream) {
        futures = stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    CompletableFutureSpliterator(CompletableFuture<T>[] futures) {
        this.futures = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(futures));
    }

    CompletableFutureSpliterator(final List<CompletableFuture<? extends T>> futures) {
        this.futures = new ArrayList<>(futures);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(final Consumer<? super T> action) {
        if (futures.isEmpty())
            return false;
        CompletableFuture.anyOf(futures.stream().toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)).join();
        // now at least one of the futures has finished, get its value and remove it
        ListIterator<CompletableFuture<? extends T>> it = futures.listIterator(futures.size());
        while (it.hasPrevious()) {
            final CompletableFuture<? extends T> future = it.previous();
            if (future.isDone()) {
                it.remove();
                action.accept(future.join());
                return true;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Should not reach here");
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
        if (futures.size() > 1) {
            int middle = futures.size() >>> 1;
            // relies on the constructor copying the list, as it gets modified in place
            Spliterator<T> result = new CompletableFutureSpliterator<>(futures.subList(0, middle));
            futures = futures.subList(middle, futures.size());
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return futures.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return IMMUTABLE | SIZED | SUBSIZED;
    }
}
```

It works by transforming the given `Stream<CompletableFuture<T>>` into a `List` of those futures.

For generating the output stream, it simply waits for any future to complete before streaming its value.

A simple non-parallel usage example (the executor is used for the `CompletableFuture`s, in order to start them all at the same time):

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
flattenStreamOfFutures(IntStream.range(0, 20)
        .mapToObj(i -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep((i % 10) * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            System.out.println("Finished " + i + " @ " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms");
            return i;
        }, executor)), false)
        .forEach(x -> {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " @ " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + "ms handle result: " + x);
        });
executor.shutdown();
```

Output:

```
Finished 10 @ 103ms
Finished 0 @ 105ms
main @ 114ms handle result: 10
main @ 114ms handle result: 0
Finished 1 @ 1102ms
main @ 1102ms handle result: 1
Finished 11 @ 1104ms
main @ 1104ms handle result: 11
Finished 2 @ 2102ms
main @ 2102ms handle result: 2
Finished 12 @ 2104ms
main @ 2105ms handle result: 12
Finished 3 @ 3102ms
main @ 3102ms handle result: 3
Finished 13 @ 3104ms
main @ 3105ms handle result: 13
…
```

As you can see, the stream produces the values almost instantly, even though the futures do not complete in order.

Applying it to the example in the question, this would give (assuming `parseLinks()` returns a `CompletableFuture<String>` instead of `~<Void>`):

```
flattenStreamOfFuturesOfStream(IntStream.range(0, 10)
                .mapToObj(this::getPage)
                // the next map() will give a Stream<CompletableFuture<Stream<String>>>
                // hence the need for flattenStreamOfFuturesOfStream()
                .map(pcf -> pcf
                        .thenApply(page -> flattenStreamOfFutures(page
                                        .getDocsId()
                                        .stream()
                                        .map(this::getDocument)
                                        .map(docCF -> docCF.thenCompose(this::parseLinks)),
                                false))),
        false)
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

<strike>Note that, if you are using this in *parallel* mode, pay attention to use a different `ForkJoinPool` for the stream and the tasks that are running behind the `CompletableFuture`'s. The stream will wait for the futures to complete, so you could actually loose performance if they share the same executor, or even run into deadlocks.</strike> – edit: I don’t think this was correct. `ForkJoinPool` should be able to deal with any blocked threads, and increase the number of threads accordingly.

Comment: Wow! Looks perfect, I'll definitely like your code. Did you meet a real situation when you need use this?

Comment: No, I just liked the challenge of this question. It clearly needs more testing.

Comment: thanks I'll test your code in a few days and say what I would get in conclusion

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have to use Streams? can't you just put some dependent actions to your `CompletableFutures`? Especially since your last call returns `CompletableFutures<Void>` (Of course, it would also be possible to use `Collection.forEach`)

```
List<CompletableFuture<Page>> completableFutures = IntStream
      .range(0, 10)
      .mapToObj(i -> getPage(i)).collect(Collectors.toList());

for (CompletableFuture<Page> page : completableFutures) {
    page.thenAccept(p -> {
        List<Integer> docsId = p.getDocsId();
        for (Integer integer : docsId) {
            getDocument(integer).thenAccept(d-> parseLinks(d));
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT: Well so I made another attempt, but I am not sure if this is a good idea, since I am not an expert on `CompletableFuture`.

Using the following method (maybe there could be a better implementation):

```
public static <T> CompletableFuture<Stream<T>> flatMapCF(Stream<CompletableFuture<T>> stream){
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync( ()->
        stream.map(CompletableFuture::join)
    );
}


Stream<CompletableFuture<Page>> pagesCFS = IntStream
        .range(0, 10)
        .mapToObj(i -> getPage(i));

CompletableFuture<Stream<Page>> pageCF = flatMapCF(pagesCFS);

CompletableFuture<Stream<Document>> docCF= 
   pageCF.thenCompose(a ->
        flatMapCF(a.flatMap(
                b -> b.getDocsId()
                        .stream()
                        .map(c -> getDocument(c))
        )));
```

The problem is probably, that that `CompletableFuture` returns only when all results are available

Comment: The problem that I don't know how many document page has. I could know this after Future completes

Comment: @mystdeim: but `p.getDocsId()` should be called after its respective `CompletableFuture<Page> page` completed, should this not be ok for you?

Comment: It's ok for but I want to get a stream of Document at the end. Maybe It's not possible with jdk 8 and I should use RxJava, because flatMap operator is existed there

Comment: @mystdeim: I have added a possible approach, but that probably needs some review.

Comment: thanks you understand what I need I like your answer. This approch does what I need, but it not fully async. I googled a bit and found that Flow from java 9 should help me. CompletableFuture wasn't created for working in stream (

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about when the operation finishes, then the following will simply trigger the `parseLinks()` on all documents:

```
IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .mapToObj(this::getPage)
        .forEach(pcf -> pcf
                .thenAccept(page -> page
                        .getDocsId()
                        .stream()
                        .map(this::getDocument)
                        .forEach(docCF -> docCF.thenCompose(this::parseLinks))));
```

Otherwise, as your last operation returns a `CompletableFuture<Void>`, I assume you would be mainly interested to know when everything is completed. You could do something like this:

```
CompletableFuture<Void> result = CompletableFuture.allOf(IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .mapToObj(this::getPage)
        .map(pcf -> pcf
                .thenCompose(page -> CompletableFuture.allOf(page
                        .getDocsId()
                        .stream()
                        .map(docId -> getDocument(docId)
                                .thenCompose(this::parseLinks))
                        .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new))))
        .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new));
```

If you are interested in the result of individual `CompletableFuture`s, the best is probably to process them directly within the stream, at the place they are created.

You could even wrap this all in a reusable method. For example, if `parseLinks()` was returning a `CompletableFuture<List<String>>`, you could define a method like this:

```
public CompletableFuture<Void> processLinks(Function<? super CompletableFuture<List<String>>, ? extends CompletableFuture<?>> processor) {
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(IntStream.range(0, 10)
            .mapToObj(this::getPage)
            .map(pcf -> pcf
                    .thenCompose(page -> CompletableFuture.allOf(page
                            .getDocsId()
                            .stream()
                            .map(docId -> getDocument(docId)
                                    .thenCompose(this::parseLinks))
                            .map(processor) // here we apply the received function
                            .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new))))
            .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new));
}
```

and process the resulting lists like this:

```
processLinks(linksCF -> linksCF
        .thenAccept(links -> links.forEach(System.out::println)));
```

The returned `CompletableFuture` would complete once all links have been printed.