# How to transform CompletableFuture<Stream<T>> to Stream<CompletableFuture<T>>?

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

That's it. Really could not find something even close. I want to implement the following chain of tasks

```
List<Item> items = Collections.singletonList(new Item("John Smith", "1997-2014"));

Stream<CompletableFuture<List<ScrappingResult>>> scrappingFutures =
    items.stream().map(item ->
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new ScrappingTask(item).call()));

Stream<CompletableFuture<ScrappingResult>> scrappingFuturesUnwrapped =
    scrappingFutures.map(resultsFuture -> ???);

Stream<CompletableFuture<TrimmingResult>> trimmingResults = scrappingFuturesUnwrapped.map(resultFuture ->
    // thenCompose?
    resultFuture.thenCompose(result -> {
        Path clipsDir = Paths.get("./"
            + result.getItem().getName()
            + "/" + result.getItem().getTimespan());

        AtomicInteger clipIdx = new AtomicInteger();

        return result.getVideo().getClips().stream()
            .map(clip -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
                new TrimmingTask(
                    ffmpegPath,
                    result.getVideo().getVideoUrl(),
                    clip,
                    clipsDir.resolve("clip_" + clipIdx.incrementAndGet() + ".mp3")).call())
            );
    });
);
```

The last line is not syntactically correct, but I hope conveys the idea. So, I want to do something like flatMap twice and get 
`Stream<CompletableFuture<TrimmingResult>>` at the end.

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Using actual code would make the question clearer.

Comment: @assylias added the code.

Comment: Your code doesn’t match what you have written in the question’s title. There is no `CompletableFuture<Stream<T>>` in you code.

Comment: Besides the mismatching title, why do you insist of complicating your code by doing *two* of these transformations?

Comment: Related: [How to divide 1 completablefuture to many completablefuture in stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39792291/525036)

Answer (score 3):

If I don't misunderstand your intention, you want to flatten the result only. you can use the `Spliterator` to receive result lazily & use `flatMap` to merge `Stream`s into a flatten stream, for example:

```
Stream<CompletableFuture<ScrappingResult>> scrappingFuturesUnwrapped =
               scrappingFutures.flatMap(each -> unwrap(each));
```

---

```
static <T> Stream<? extends CompletableFuture<T>> 
  unwrap(CompletableFuture<? extends List<? extends T>> master) {

    return generate(new Predicate<Consumer<? super CompletableFuture<T>>>() {

        private Iterator<? extends T> cursor;

        @Override
        public boolean test(Consumer<? super CompletableFuture<T>> consumer) {
            cursor = cursor == null ? await().iterator() : cursor;
            if (cursor.hasNext()) {
                consumer.accept(completedFuture(cursor.next()));
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        //                        v--- blocked at the first time
        private List<? extends T> await() {
            try {
                return master.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                throw new CompletionException(e);
            }
        }
    });
}

static <T> Stream<? extends CompletableFuture<T>> 
  generate(Predicate<Consumer<? super CompletableFuture<T>>> generator) {

    long unknownSize = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    return stream(new AbstractSpliterator<CompletableFuture<T>>(unknownSize, 0) {
        public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super CompletableFuture<T>> action) {
            return generator.test(action);
        }
    }, false);
}
```

### Summary

The solution above is just my first thought and it isn't the best approach in this case, you can think it against with [big design first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Design_Up_Front). However, even if it is a poor solution but I'll keep it here since it maybe give somebody thinking in other ways. for more details, you can see the comments of @Holger from here and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48561183/replace-for-loop-with-java-8-foreach-for-updating-values/48561991?noredirect=1#comment84126733_48561991).

I admit the best approach is what @Holger have said below, since there is no one write it down, please let me record it to serve more people.

```
Stream<CompletableFuture<ScrappingResult>> scrappingFuturesUnwrapped =
               scrappingFutures.flatMap(each -> each.join().stream())
                               .map(CompletableFuture::completedFuture);
```

Comment: I don’t understand the purpose of this separation into the two methods `unwrap` and `generate`. What you have written in `test` could have been placed directy into the `tryAdvance` method. But anyway, it’s not more lazy than a simple `.flatMap(each -> each.join().stream()) .map(CompletableFuture::completedFuture)`…

Comment: @Holger yes, sir. I agree, after answer it I found it can simplify it as yours. but I want to show the usage of the `Spliterator` at first time, maybe it is overhead, :)

Comment: @Holger I used `Predicate` to separate the iteration logic out of the `generate`. we can think of adapt a `Predicate`  to a `Spliterator`. am I right, sir?

Comment: There is no real separation here, as 99% of the logic is within the `unwrap` method and since the `Predicate` deals with an `Iterator`, it bears iteration logic anyway.

Comment: @Holger thanks for your audit. so is the answer an anti-pattern? could you give me some keywords or suggestion? I'm interested in it.

Comment: @Holger in fact, there is no `generate` method in the first worked around code. while I remember the `Stream#generate`, it was extracted with `Predicate` after I found there is no suitable built-in functional interface in jdk, :)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a `Stream<CompletableFuture<T>>` to a `CompletableFuture<Stream<T>>` using [`Stream.reduce`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce(T,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)):

```
static <T> CompletableFuture<Stream<T>> reduce(Stream<CompletableFuture<T>> futures) {
    return futures
        .map(future -> future.thenApply(Stream::of))
        .reduce(
            CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Stream.empty()),
            MyClass::combine);
}
```

For this to work, we still need to define a helper function `combine` for combining two instances of `CompletableFuture<Stream<T>>` that concatenates the stream inside of the individual futures:

```
static <T>CompletableFuture<Stream<T>> combine(CompletableFuture<Stream<T>> future1, CompletableFuture<Stream<T>> future2) {
    return future1
        .thenCompose(stream1 -> future2
        .thenApply(stream2 -> Stream.concat(stream1, stream2)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general you cannot perform this sort of reversing. In functional categories language, you have two functors between the following categories:

```
T --> Stream<T>
Stream<T> --> CompletableFuture<Stream<T>>
```

You simply do not have a functor between

```
T --> CompletableFuture<T>
CompletableFuture<T> --> Stream<CompletableFuture<T>>
```

If you don't want to care about the outer `CompletableFuture` and need `Stream` semantic, you need some sort of `StreamT` [monad transfomer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_transformer). Java currently do not have higher-kinded types support, so I'm not sure (but maybe applying some non-standard tricks) it is possible to implement something like `StreamT`

Comment: Not sure I agree with the first one. T--> CompletableFuture<T> as follows final CompletableFuture<String> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(new Supplier<String>() ....

Comment: @user889742 Do not quite understand what you mean. Of course we can use, according to monad definition we need to have `pure(t: T): M[T]`, but from just `T --> CompletableFuture<Stream<T>>` we cannot construct `T --> Stream<CompletableFuture<T>>`. If you have a map between some sets `A --> B --> C`, can you construct `A --> C --> B`? Makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

[michid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402428/michid)'s answer works and is the most purely functional, but it's a bit inefficient because it creates a "linked list" of nested concatenated singleton streams, something like this:

```
concat(of(A),
       concat(of(B),
              concat(of(C), ...)))
```

So, here's a more efficient (albeit not purely functional) version, which only requires the creation of a single intermediate array of all the futures:

```
static <T> CompletableFuture<Stream<T>> allOfStream(Stream<CompletableFuture<T>> stream) {
  CompletableFuture<T>[] futuresArray = futures.<CompletableFuture<T>>toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
  return CompletableFuture.allOf(futuresArray)
    .thenApply(ignored -> Arrays.stream(futuresArray).map(CompletableFuture::join));
}
```

This is still non-blocking, since the lambda in `thenApply` will only be invoked if all the futures in `allOf` succeeded, and so the `join` call on each future will also return immediately - it will effectively just be an "unwrap" operation from `CompletableFuture<T>` to `T`.

But it is eager, ie it won't work on infinite streams, since `toArray` will never terminate. I'm not sure what the behavior would be of the purely functional answer for infinite streams.