# Replace for loop with java 8 foreach for updating values

Tags: java, lambda, foreach, java-8, java-stream

I'm looking to replace the following for loop with an elegant java 8 stream or lambda solution. Is there anything concise and efficient?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>( Arrays.asList( 10,-3,5));

        // add 1/2 of previous element to each element
        for(int i =1 ;i < myList.size();  ++i )
            myList.set(i, myList.get(i)+myList.get(i-1)/2);

        // myList.skip(1).forEach( e -> e + prevE/2 );  // looking for something in this spirit
    }
```

Comment: You try to change an element depending on some other element. But the *stream API* is part of Javas *functional programming* facility and a major concept of FP is that each element is processd *independend* of the others. Therefore javas *stream API* is not the right tool.

Comment: Try use `replaceAll` method

Comment: @HadiJ not really, since it requires some previous state

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your loop evaluation has a dependency to the result of the previous evaluation. It is equivalent to

```
for(int i = 1, value = myList.get(0); i < myList.size(); i++ ) {
    value = myList.get(i) + value/2;
    myList.set(i, value);
}
```

There is no real simplification by using the Stream API or lambda expressions possible. In fact, I would prefer the variant shown above, even if it’s bigger rather than smaller, as it makes clear what actually happens (and may be slightly more efficient by avoiding multiple `List` lookups).

It also allows you to program position independent, if you create a new `List`:

```
List<Integer> srcList = Arrays.asList(10, -3, 5), dstList = new ArrayList<>();

int value = 0;
for(Integer i: srcList) {
    value = i + value/2;
    dstList.add(value);
}
```

Comment: I prefer your invariant approach, since it never change the states of the original list. :)

Comment: hi, @Holger. excuse me, after read your answer, I have another idea, how about writing a custom `Spliterator`? Am I overhead again?

Comment: @holi-java that’s what I mean with “no real simplification”. You can do it, but since the function is not associative, there is no way to provide efficient splitting support, so you end up with more complicated code for no real benefit.

Comment: oh, my god. I finally understand what you have said to me last days. please forgive my bad english, I admit I think it overhead from here to there, but there is no significant benefits. thanks very much.

Answer (score 6):

There is no way to access previous element in the java stream. 
You might use `IntStream#range` but it doesn't look elegant:

```
IntStream.range(1, myList.size())
        .forEachOrdered(i -> myList.set(i, myList.get(i) + myList.get(i - 1) / 2));
```

Comment: Agreed, sometimes a for loop is all you need.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can achieve this using this line of code:

```
IntStream.range(1,myList.size())
    .forEachOrdered(i->myList.set(i,(myList.get(i)+myList.get(i-1)/2)));
System.out.println(myList);
```

Comment: @Eugene If I add `parallel()`, for this particular list, I achieve the same result.

Comment: You're right. Updated my answer. I haven't tested, i was just writing code from my tablet.

Comment: So you think this is more elegant?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès IMHO, the regular for loop looks better, but I only showed to the OP the way we can achieve this using `forEach()` method.