# Streams Java 8 - Refactoring stream code

Tags: java-8, refactoring, java-stream

I need to refactor my below stream code:

```
    List<Map<String, Integer>> list5 = new ArrayList<>();
    map3 = new HashMap<>();
    map3.put("foo", 1);
    map3.put("bar", 2);
    map3.put("zzz", 6);
    list5.add(map3);
    map3 = new HashMap<>();
    map3.put("foo", 3);
    map3.put("bar", 4);
    map3.put("zzz", null);
    list5.add(map3);

    //new list with processed maps
    List<Map<String, Integer>> list6 = list5.stream()
            .map(hashmap -> {
                Map<String, Integer> newMap = hashmap.entrySet().stream()
                        .collect(HashMap::new, (m, v) -> {
                            if (v.getKey().equals("bar")) {
                                m.put(v.getKey(), v.getValue() * 2);
                            } else {
                                m.put(v.getKey(), v.getValue());
                            }
                        }, HashMap::putAll);
                return newMap;
            })
            .collect(toList());
    System.out.println(list6);
```

I need a way to extract/refactor the below logic only from the above stream code, since this piece will only change in other list of maps that I have:

```
if (v.getKey().equals("bar")) {
    m.put(v.getKey(), v.getValue() * 2);
} else {
    m.put(v.getKey(), v.getValue());
}
```

Using IntelliJ it adds a biconsumer to main() itself, which is not expected here and removes the code. I need a way to extract it separately something like below:

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> list6 = list5.stream()
            .map(hashmap -> {
                Map<String, Integer> newMap = hashmap.entrySet().stream()
                        .collect(HashMap::new, (m, v) -> {
                            biconsumerLogic1.accept(m, v);
                        }, HashMap::putAll);
                return newMap;
            })
            .collect(toList());
```

And biconsumerLogic1 is a separate functional interface like:

```
BiConsumer biconsumerLogic1() {
    accept(m, v) {
         //logic goes here...
    }
}
```

How do I achieve that? Any pointers are appreciated.

Thanks..

Comment: It would be better if you tell what you are trying to do here. may be someone has a better solution than refactoring your code

Comment: Please see my comment below @Bohemian

Comment: Yes I will be doing that.. Thanks for reminding though.. SO does not allow me today, I guess I can't except my own answer within 24 hrs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is my version of the refactoring using BiConsumers:

```
psv main(...) {
    List<Map<String, Integer>> newList = processMapData(origList, accumulator());
    System.out.println(newList);
}

private static List<Map<String, Integer>> processMapData(List<Map<String, Integer>> origList, BiConsumer<HashMap<String, Integer>, Map.Entry<String, Integer>> accumulator) {
    return origList.stream()
                .map(hashmap -> {
                    Map<String, Integer> newMap = hashmap.entrySet().stream()
                            .collect(HashMap::new, accumulator, HashMap::putAll);
                    return newMap;
                })
                .collect(toList());
}

private static BiConsumer<HashMap<String, Integer>, Map.Entry<String, Integer>> accumulator() {
    return (m, v) -> {
        m.put(v.getKey(), v.getKey().equals("bar") ? v.getValue() * 2: v.getValue());
    };
}
```

I could leverage more control and dynamically inject accumulators to `processMapData` function.
Thanks to @Federico for the BiConsumer function suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

See, the problem is with using streams at all. You have overdesigned it, you don't need most of it.

Look:

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> newList = new ArrayList<>(list);

newList.replaceAll(eachMap -> {
  Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(eachMap);
  map.computeIfPresent("bar", (k,v) -> v * 2);
  return map;
});
```

And to replace the action, you need to do something like this:

```
BiFunction<String, Integer, Integer> action = (k,v) -> v * 2;

newList.replaceAll(eachMap -> {
  Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>(eachMap);
  map.computeIfPresent("bar", action);
  return map;
});
```

Now you can extract the whole thing into a separate method and accept `list` and `action` (possibly the `"bar"` variable as well) as arguments, and here you have your value replacer.

Comment: You have simplified the operation to a degree that makes abstracting the modification unnecessary.

Comment: @Holger, the main thing OP wants (which I missed initially as well) is to abstract the operation (the `v -> v*2` part) and reuse everything else.

Comment: It’s not clear whether the OP wants to abstract the modification function only or both, the key selection and the modification (as the original function was the entire `if (v.getKey().equals("bar")) { m.put(v.getKey(), v.getValue() * 2); } else { m.put(v.getKey(), v.getValue()); }`). In the latter case, your operation merely consists of exactly that function. Ok, plus the map duplication, but the abstraction itself would also add another declaration, so it’s not simpler than just writing a single function. But let the OP decide…

Comment: @Holger, The map duplication came from original question. I don't know it it's required, but the piece did it, so I did too. As for the operation, it really can go either way. If we have a requirement to do both single key replacement and occasionally replace two keys at once, we can expose a `Consumer<Map<String, Integer>>` for `map` variable.

Comment: I didn’t object the map duplication. You gave a very good answer and all I said, is, that I would prefer your first variant and forget about abstracting the actual action further, but in the end, it’s up to the OP…

Comment: you like as me think more for the OP. since we are not consumer but provider, think more is hard to change, if the direction is wrong. just make it KISS. for more details, you  can see the comments of @Holger from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48561183/replace-for-loop-with-java-8-foreach-for-updating-values/48561991?noredirect=1#comment84126733_48561991), :)

Comment: Thanks all for your wonderful inputs. These insights into stream API and different approach to solve the same problem in an elegant and concise manner are awesome. (at)Holger I just wanted to extract the modification piece of the pipeline as the outer piece is going to remain the same. (at)M.Prokhorov you guys nailed it very well

Comment: Another intention was not to mutate the same collection and create a new one. Also as I mentioned in my example, my dataset could have null values in the map, hence I went that route of creating a new hashmap. toMap() was resulting in NPE as it internally calls HashMap.merge() which has a explicit check on null values and throws NPE. So I researched a bit more and came up with that solution.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I see a problem. replaceAll is mutating the List. Though Its creating new Maps in the list and replace existing ones, but doesn't it goes against the principles of using stream (DO NOT mutate the underlying collection)?

Comment: @GauravSaini, it does mutate, but it mutates a `newList`, not original one. It doesn't use any `Stream`s, just collections themselves and lambdas. Technically, there is no reason why it couldn't create and run a stream, but my aim was to show that you can do without it and get a clear looking code that does the same thing.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov It does looks clean, but i see few code smell here. 1> You iterate the list twice, which is bad for large data set. Once when you create a new list, secondly when you are doing replace all. So effectively your solution is doing 2x operations, whereas my solution though hard to read still manages everything in just 1 iteration of list through streams.

Comment: @GauravSaini, it also works with the maps slightly longer than a single iteration would do, although that's harder to assess operation-wise, because it depends on how many hash buckets they would have. I still mostly stand by my solution, but it's indeed not perfect.

Comment: @GauravSaini, also note that `Stream` operations do not directly correspond to collection operation in terms of performance. I may have iterated the list twice, but for certain cases it may still be faster than streaming the same. I would not optimize for single iteration in cases where it makes it harder to understand what's going on, unless it's proven that readable code creates unnecessary hotspots.

Comment: @GauravSaini you are overestimating the costs of iterating. There are too many factors affecting the performance, e.g. smaller loops might get better optimized by the JVM or have better chance to fit into the CPU’s instruction cache. In this specific case, copying from one `ArrayList` to another boils down to an intrinsic array copy operation that likely works much faster than processing elements individually. Especially for large data sets and comparing with a Stream solution, as `Collectors.toList()` gets no hint about the initial capacity, so filling the result list is really less efficient

Comment: @Holger let me ask you this... would it be hard to actually add this features about initial capacity? I've been thinking about this and trying to figure out a way, but could not... this is obviously theoretically

Comment: @Eugene a general solution would require a different interface. But for a lot of cases, e.g. when combining collectors, there wouldn’t be a useful hint anyway. In principle, there could be an internal tweak, when the builtin `toList()` returns a collector implementation which the builtin `Stream.collect` implementation recognizes.

Comment: ... but doing that would very quickly devolve implementation of `Stream.collect` into a mess of type checks, not to mention the fact that there also is the case for parallel processing and that would be even worse.

Answer (score 2):

I think there are better ways to do what you're actually doing. But strictly answering *how to extract and refactor the indicated piece of code*, you could do something like this:

```
static <K, V> List<Map<K, V>> process(
        List<Map<K, V>> source,
        BiConsumer<? super Map<K, V>, ? super Map.Entry<K, V>> accumulator) {

    return source.stream()
        .map(m -> m.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(HashMap::new, accumulator, Map::putAll))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Map<String, Integer>> list6 = process(
    list5,
    (m, e) -> m.put(
        e.getKey(), 
        e.getKey().equals("bar") ? e.getValue() * 2 : e.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
list5.stream().forEach(map -> map.replaceAll((k,v) -> k.equals("bar") ? v * 2 : v));
```

This does an in-place replacement of values.

If you absolutely need a *new* map:

```
list6 = list5.stream()
    .map(m -> m.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue() * (e.getKey().equals("bar") ?  2 : 1))))
    .collect(toList());
```

If you're looking to refactor, there are two options:

#### Option 1:

Create a `BiFunction`, eg:

```
public static BiFunction<String, Integer, Integer> valueCalculator() {
    return (k,v) -> k.equals("bar") ? v * 2 : v;
}
```

and to use:

```
list5.stream().forEach(map -> map.replaceAll(valueCalculator()));
```

#### Option 2:

Create a method:

```
public Integer valueCalculator(String key, Integer value) {
    return key.equals("bar") ? value * 2 : value;
}
```

and to use, use a *method reference*:

```
list5.stream().forEach(map -> map.replaceAll(this::valueCalculator));
```

of if it's a `static` method:

```
list5.stream().forEach(map -> map.replaceAll(MyClass::valueCalculator));
```

I prefer option 2, because it's easier understand, test and debug.

Comment: Nope. My outer stream code is going to remain same. Only part that is going to change is the if () {} logic. Here I am changing values by doing multiplication, but I may have a logic to do something else. SO I want to inject that logic dynamically. and I can have several such scenarios.

Comment: @GauravSaini I've added some options of how to refactor

Comment: `replaceAll` is a big overkill when you only concerned with changing the value of a single key. This is what `computeIfPresent` is for.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov sure it's overkill, but it's not a problem if the map is small. Programmer productivity counts too.

Comment: @Bohemian, I would argue that there is no productivity gain in saying "replace everything here" when in reality you only actuall want the single thing changed, and everything else to stay the same. Unless we do want to leave the ability to change multiple keys at once, using `All` would pollute the intention. I know I would be confused when I came across this. And the next guy, and the next. This means gaining a little for one person, and losing some for the rest (and you yourself is a different person the next day when you read what you wrote the day before).