# How to sequence a task to execute once all Single's in a collection complete

Tags: reactive, completable-future, helidon, dbclient

I am using [Helidon DBClient transactions](https://helidon.io/docs/v2/apidocs/io.helidon.dbclient/io/helidon/dbclient/DbClient.html#inTransaction(java.util.function.Function)) and have found myself in a situation where I end up with a list of Singles, `List<Single<T>>` and want to perform the next task only after completing all of the singles.

I am looking for something of equivalent to CompletableFuture.allOf() but with [Single](https://helidon.io/docs/v2/apidocs/io.helidon.common.reactive/io/helidon/common/reactive/Single.html).

I could map each of the single toCompletableFuture() and then do a CompletableFuture.allOf() on top, but is there a better way? Could someone point me in the right direction with this?

--

Why did I end up with a List<Single>?

I have a collection of POJOs which I turn into named insert .execute() all within an open transaction. Since I .stream() the original collection and perform inserts using the .map() operator, I end up with a List when I terminate the stream to collect a List. None of the inserts might have actually been executed. At this point, I want to wait until all of the Singles have been completed before I proceed to the next stage.

This is something I would naturally do with a CompletableFuture.allOf(), but I do not want to change the API dialect for just this and stick to Single/Multi.

Comment: This answer shows how to convert a `CompletableFuture<Stream<T>>` to a `Stream<CompletableFuture<T>>` using `Stream.reduce`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74452659/402428. You should be able to generalize / adapt this to your use case.

Comment: @michid Thanks for the tip, definitely there are multiple ways through CompletableFutures, but I don't want to switch to CF just for this case.

Comment: Meanwhile, I pummeled something like the below which appears to be doing the job -
single<T> = Multi.just(List<Single<T>>)
                              .flatMap(Functions.identity())
                              .reduce(supplier, reducer)
This is on the same lines but sticks to Single/Multi dialect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Single.flatMap`, `Single.flatMapSingle`, `Multi.flatMap` will effectively inline the future represented by the publisher passed as argument.

You can convert a `List<Single<T>>` to `Single<List<T>>` like this:

```
List<Single<Integer>> listOfSingle = List.of(Single.just(1), Single.just(2));
Single<List<Integer>> singleOfList = Multi.just(listOfSingle)
                                          .flatMap(Function.identity())
                                          .collectList();
```

Things can be tricky when you are dealing with `Single<Void>` as Void cannot be instantiated and `null` is not a valid value (i.e. `Single.just(null)` throws a `NullPointerException`).

```
// convert List<Single<Void>> to Single<List<Void>>
Single<List<Void>> listSingle =
        Multi.just(List.of(Single.<Void>empty(), Single.<Void>empty()))
             .flatMap(Function.identity())
             .collectList();

// convert Single<List<Void>> to Single<Void>
// Void cannot be instantiated, it needs to be casted from null
// BUT null is not a valid value...
Single<Void> single = listSingle.toOptionalSingle()
                                // convert Single<List<Void>> to Single<Optional<List<Void>>>
                                // then Use Optional.map to convert Optional<List<Void>> to Optional<Void>
                                .map(o -> o.map(i -> (Void) null))
                                // convert Single<Optional<Void>> to Single<Void>
                                .flatMapOptional(Function.identity());

// Make sure it works
single.forSingle(o -> System.out.println("ok"))
      .await();
```

Comment: Multi.just followed by flatMap operator works. Thanks!