# Merging three Completeable futures into one with Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, future, completable-future

The following 3 methods return `CompleteableFuture<JsonObject>`, The content I need is on the value property of the JsonObject so ultimately I would need to do something like response.getJsonArray("value")

```
CompletableFuture<JsonObject> completeableFuture1 = entityService.getProducts();
CompletableFuture<JsonObject> completeableFuture2 = entityService.getCustomers();
CompletableFuture<JsonObject> completeableFuture3 = entityService.getOrders();
```

Once I successfully retrieve these 3 pieces I would like to continue with the remainder of my code that depends on them. I will need access to all 3 lists: products, customers, orders.

After doing some research I think I need to use allOf(), but having trouble figuring out the correct syntax to piece it all together.

Comment: Related: combining a stream of futures into a future for a stream: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74452659/402428

Answer (score 2):

Let's use this to simulate the delay (PS: I am returning string instead of json object):

```
public CompletableFuture<String> getProduct() {
    return waitAndReturn(2000, "product  ready");
}
public CompletableFuture<String> getCustomers() {
    return waitAndReturn(2000, "customers ready");
}
public CompletableFuture<String> getOrders() {
    return waitAndReturn(2000, "customers ready");
}

private CompletableFuture<String> waitAndReturn(int millis, String string) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
            return string;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Next, as you mentioned, we need to use the `CompletableFuture.allOf` method. This is going to run the 3 methods in parallel and return a `CompletableFuture<Void>` as it's result.

```
var cust = getCustomers();
var prod = getProduct();
var order = getOrders();

CompletableFuture<Void> all = CompletableFuture.allOf(
        cust, prod, order
);
```

On this resulting future, we can call the `thenRun` and pass a lambda expression. This is going to be ran when the 3 initial futures are ready, and therefore, we can call the `join` method on each of them, to get the data out:

```
@Test
void test() throws InterruptedException {

    var cust = getCustomers();
    var prod = getProduct();
    var order = getOrders();

    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    CompletableFuture.allOf(
            cust, prod, order
    ).thenRun(() -> {
        String customerJson = cust.join();
        String productJson = prod.join();
        String orderJson = order.join();
        System.out.println(customerJson + productJson + orderJson);
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    });

    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

Later edited: as per discussed in the comments.

If you want to return a `CompletableFuture<>` without blocking and waiting, you can approach it slightly differently: `thenRun` is like the equivalent of forEach for streams, you can imagine it as a final operation.

However, you can use `thenApply`which will be more like a `stream.map`: it will allow you to process the 3 futures and combine them into a new one. I'll stick to the String example instead of jsonObjects:

```
CompletableFuture<String> result = CompletableFuture.allOf(
                cust, prod, order
        ).thenApply(__ -> {
            String customerJson = cust.join();
            String productJson = prod.join();
            String orderJson = order.join();
            return customerJson + productJson + orderJson;
        });
```

As you can see, the function inside `thenApply` returns a String and the resulting type of is now a `CompletableFuture<String>`. You can now return this from your function and somebody else can continue adding other intermediary steps `thenApply(...)` or consume it `thenRun()`.

I hope the comparison with streams will make it easier to grasp the information. For a very well explained and more in-depth tutorial, watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ueIL0SwEWI

Comment: Thank you very much for this response. I do have one quick question... if I ultimately need to do logic on those 3 lists and return a single CompleteableFuture<JsonArray> from my function, is .thenRun still the right thing to use?

Comment: Sorry maybe you can help me figure this final piece out. Once I have all 3 values inside of the allOf(), I need to do some logic on them and then ultimately return a CompletableFuture<JsonObject> from my function. When I try "return CompletableFuture.allOf(...)" I am getting an error because it is CompletableFuture<Void> when I need to return my final result which needs to be CompletableFuture<JsonObject> (which I construct with my custom logic)

Comment: hey, i have updated my answer to address this additional question. hope it helps, take a look.

Comment: This helped so much! I was able to use thenApply on the allOf future and then return what I needed. My only remaining question is about the __ added to thenApply(). I am assuming since allOf returns a CompletableFuture<Void>, __ represents void and that is our only option here.

Comment: yes, the `thenApply` method's should accept a lambda with an argument to keep the same signature consistent with the others. It's common practice to use `__` or `igonre` as names for parameters which are not meant to be used. I'm glad it helped!