# Filtering a stream of CompletableFuture<SomeObject> on some attribute of SomeObject

Tags: java, java-stream, completable-future

I have a Stream of CompletableFuture of SomeObject and I'm trying to filter this on some attribute of SomeObject and I can't seem to find a satisfying way to filter this.

```java
public class SomeObject {
    private String someAttribute;

    public String getSomeAttribute() {
        return someAttribute;
    } 
}
```

I tried this, but I'm wondering if there is a non-blocking way ?

```java
  public List<CompletableFuture<SomeObject>> filterStream(Stream<CompletableFuture<SomeObject>> stream) {
        return stream.filter(futureSomeObject -> {
            try {
                return futureSomeObject.get().getSomeAttribute().equals("SOMETHING");
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                return false;
            }
        }).toList();
  }
```

I also thought of something like this, but I'll need to change the return signature :

```java
stream.map(CompletableFuture::join).filter(object -> object.getSomeAttribute().equals("SOMETHING")).toList();
```

Comment: You could already improve the first solution using `join()` instead of `get()`, however the return type is constraining you to wait for all completions to be able to build the list. I can only advise to change the return type to something more meaningful, either `CompletableFuture<List<SomeObject>>` or `Stream<SomeObject>`, possibly using my [`flattenStreamOfFutures()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40225858/525036) if you don’t care about order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments it seems this is the way I was looking for:

```java
public List<CompletableFuture<SomeObject>> filterStream(Stream<CompletableFuture<SomeObject>> stream) {
   return stream.filter(f -> f.join().getSomeAttribute().equals("SOMETHING")).toList()
}
```

Comment: That's still blocking.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must keep the return type you can map back from `List<SomeObject>` to `List<CompletableFuture<SomeObject>>` in your second approach:

```
stream
    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
    .filter(object -> object.getSomeAttribute().equals("SOMETHING"))
    .map(CompletableFuture::completedFuture)
    .toList();
```

Note that this approach is still blocking though. A simple way to obtain a unblocking solution is wrapping your second approach itself into a `CompletableFuture`. However this would also impact the return type and turn it into `CompletableFuture<List<SomeObject>>`.

Comment: How is that better than `stream.filter(f -> f.join().getSomeAttribute().equals("SOMETHING")) .toList()`?

Comment: Not better, but it keeps the original return type, as desired by the OP.

Comment: The OP’s variant, just using `filter`, does already keep the original return type. My variant only replaces `get` with `join` to eliminate the need for verbose `try … catch …` syntax, but is otherwise equivalent, in other words, also keeps the original return type. There is no need to create new `CompletableFuture` instances.

Comment: > replaces get with join
I missed this nuance. Probably worth making this into an answer on its own emphasizing this.